# Retrieve data from MySQL DB using java

Tags: java, mysql

In here i want to obtain data from the MySQL DB & run the play method.but it execute at once.i wanted to get row one information pass that in to the ply method & get the second row information & pass it to the play method so on.
please help me to resolve this.
thank u in advance.

public class Player {

```
static Play PL = new Play();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        Statement stmt = null;
        // connect to database radio
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/radio", "root", "");
        stmt=conn.createStatement();

            String sql = "SELECT Link FROM split";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
                while(rs.next()){
                    //Retrieve by column name

                    int numColumns = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();

                    for ( int i = 1 ; i <= numColumns ; i++ ) {

                        System.out.println(numColumns);
                        String SongLocation = rs.getString(i);

                    System.out.println(SongLocation);

                    PL.play(SongLocation);

                    System.out.println("playing song");   

                    }
          }

    } catch (SQLException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looping through columns by using

```
int numColumns = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
for ( int i = 1 ; i <= numColumns ; i++ ) {
 ...
```

instead try using a while loop

```
 while (rs.next()) {
 ...
```

and because you need the index, inlude a local variable int i, that you just increment after each while loop

Comment: Thank u.I got where i have gone wrong.
bt still  
while (rs.next()) {
doesn't help me to go through one by one.
is there any way to obtain row number and lope through it..